# PigLatin program help...Capitalize?

Tags: java

I have the program working except for the capitalization part:
Here's how to translate the English word englishWord into the Pig Latin word pigLatinWord:
a.  If there are no vowels in englishWord, then pigLatinWord is just englishWord + "ay". (There are ten vowels: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u', and their uppercase counterparts.)
b.  Else, if englishWord begins with a vowel, then pigLatinWord is just englishWord + "yay".
c.  Otherwise (if englishWord has a vowel in it and yet doesn't start with a vowel), then pigLatinWord is end + start + "ay", where end and start are defined as follows:
1.  Let start be all of englishWord up to (but not including) its first vowel.
2.  Let end be all of englishWord from its first vowel on.
3.  But, if englishWord is capitalized, then capitalize end and "uncapitalize" start.

How do you do the capitalization part? 
So far, I get Hasta= astaHay. It should be Hasta = Astahay

Here is the basic program so far:

```
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
 if (c == 'a' && c == 'A') {
  return true;
 } else if (c == 'e' && c == 'E') {
  return true;
 } else if (c == 'i' || c == 'I') {
  return true;
 } else if (c == 'o' || c == 'O') {
  return true;
 } else if (c == 'u' || c == 'U') {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}

public static String convertPigLatinWord(String englishWord) {
 int length = englishWord.length();
 if (englishWord.charAt(length - 1) == '.' && englishWord.charAt(length - 1) == '!' && englishWord.charAt(length - 1) == '?') {

  char ch = englishWord.charAt(0);
  String rest = englishWord.substring(1, length - 1);
  return (rest + ch + "ay" + englishWord.charAt(length - 1) + "\"" + " ");

 } else if (isVowel(englishWord.charAt(0))) {
  return (englishWord + "yay" + " ");
 } else {
  char ch = englishWord.charAt(0);
  String rest = englishWord.substring(1);
  return (rest + ch + "ay" + " ");
 }

}
public String translate() {
 String pigLatinPhrase = "";
 while (englishPhrase.length() > 1) {
  String word = getWord();
  pigLatinPhrase += convertPigLatinWord(word) + " ";
 }
 return pigLatinPhrase;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

 String answer = "";
 do {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input;
  System.out.print("Please enter an English phrase: ");
  input = keyboard.nextLine();
  PigLatin3 first = new PigLatin3(input);
  System.out.println(first.translate());
  System.out.println("Would you like to translate another phrase? (y or n)");
  answer = keyboard.nextLine();

 } while (!(answer.equals("N")) && !(answer.equals("n")));
 System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: Here are some words you may not have considered: "my" and "by." Per your instructions, these would translate to "myay" and "byay."

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel I get ymay for my and ybay for by.

Comment: `(c == 'a' && c == 'A')` should be `(c == 'a' || c == 'A')`, same for `E`.

Comment: @nehaarsha "_If there are no vowels in englishWord, then pigLatinWord is just englishWord + "ay". (There are ten vowels: 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', and 'u', and their uppercase counterparts.)_" According to your definition of vowels, those words have no vowels.

Comment: @JoelA.Christophel how can i fix this?

Comment: Well, it seems that in some cases you will need to treat "y" as a vowel. However, consider "your". The Pig Latin translation is not "youray"; it is "ouryay". So in certain cases the "y" acts as a consonant.

Answer (score 1):

You can capitalize a letter by breaking the string to substrings and then capitalizing them:

```
String word = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
```

So just use the toUpperCase() and toLowerCase() methods of String ...

There is also a neat trick that you can use with single characters based on the ASCII table. Just xor them with 32 to get the other case.

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
public static String onlyFirstLetterUpperCase(String a){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        if("AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(a.charAt(i)) != -1 )
             break;
        // indexOf looks for a char in a given string and returns its 
        // position or -1 if not found. So if this indexOf returns -1 I can be sure, 
        // that the character is not a vowel
    }
    return a.substring(0, i + 1).toUpperCase() + a.substring(i + 1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Just call this method after performing your operations

Comment: but I am supposed to capitalize from the start of the first vowel. the method that you suggested would only work for the word "Hasta"

Comment: so just find out the location of the first vowel the string (you can do this by using a loop and breaking out of it when you reach the first vowel) and then replace 1 in the method with this new location. I will update my answer...

Comment: I did some bad indexing, now it should work as expected

Comment: @ Void how would i call the method? i put my runner up.

Comment: replace return pigLatinPhrase; 
with
return onlyFirstLetterUpperCase(pigLatinPhrase);

Comment: I would put it in your translate method, just replace the return statement.